# How to use Applescript text item delimiters while ignoring a specific character

Tags: applescript

I would like to separate every URL in a text list with a comma in an Applescript application. An example input would be:

> alloresto.fr eat.ch eatnow.com.au just-eat.ca just-eat.co.uk

Using Applescript's text item delimiters, I get partial success:

```
set enterDomains to myTextField's stringValue() as text -- gets text from text field in my xib window

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ", "
set theResults to every word of enterDomains as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
```

> alloresto.fr, eat.ch, eatnow.com.au, just, eat.ca, just, eat.co.uk

But this breaks every domain with a `-` in it since I have it set to `every word`. Is it possible to ignore the `-` character when using Applescript's text item delimiters?

I know my issue is located with `every word of enterDomains` since hyphenated domains contain more than one word but when I change this line to something like `text of enterDomains`, it returns me the same list of domains as a result without any added commas.

Ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. The text item delimiters is so that you can get the _text items_ of something. You are not doing that, so there is no point to playing with the text item delimiters in the first place.

Comment: Also this is inconsistent: are there commas in `myTextField's stringValue()` or not? If not there seems little point in adding them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `words of...` versus `text items of...`

***`words of...`*** functions independently of `text item delimiters`, so will always split a string in the same way.

`text item delimiters` allows you to specify one or more phrases at which to delimit a string to be separated into a list of ***`text items`***.  It also determines how a list of `text items` are joined together, so will be significant in any instance where a `list` object is coerced into `text` (or `string`) object.

To split a string at every occurrence of a space character, and only a space character:

```
set enterDomains to "alloresto.fr eat.ch eatnow.com.au just-eat.ca just-eat.co.uk"
set my text item delimiters to space
set theResults to text items in enterDomains
    --> {"alloresto.fr", "eat.ch", "eatnow.com.au", "just-eat.ca", "just-eat.co.uk"}
```

Then, to join this list of `text items` into a string, delimited by a comma-space:

```
# ...Cont'd from the previous code block

set my text item delimiters to ", "
return theResults as text
    --> "alloresto.fr, eat.ch, eatnow.com.au, just-eat.ca, just-eat.co.uk"
```

#### `text item delimiters` more generally

As I stated above, `text item delimiters` can actually be set to a *list* of several items, instead of just a single character or phrase.  This causes a string to be split at every occurrence of every item in your specified list of `text item delimiters`, e.g.

```
set input to "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
set my text item delimiters to {"i", space, "fox"}
get the text items of the input
    --> {"The", "qu", "ck", "brown", "", "", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog."}
```

The order of the delimiters does not matter here, because a string will be split using every delimiter acting in a simultaneous fashion.

However, when joining the `list` back up into a `text` object, **only the first** delimiter is used to glue the `text items` back together.  In this case, it will be the `"i"`:

```
# ...Cont'd from the previous code block
# result: {"The", "qu", "ck", "brown", "", "", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog."}

return the result as text
    --> "Theiquickibrowniiijumpsioveritheilazyidog."
```

Notice that when a string is split, every occurrence of a delimiter is deleted from the string; when it is joined, the first delimiter only is inserted in between each chunk of text.  This is effectively *replacing* bits of text with something else.

#### Text replacement using `text item delimiters` (An introduction)

In your specific case, your task can be summarised as needing to replace the spaces in your string with comma-spaces.  So we can do this in a single move, by setting the `text item delimiters` such that space characters are deleted, and `", "` is inserted during concatenation:

```
set enterDomains to "alloresto.fr eat.ch eatnow.com.au just-eat.ca just-eat.co.uk"
set my text item delimiters to {", ", space}
return the text items of enterDomains as text
    --> "alloresto.fr eat.ch, eatnow.com.au just-eat.ca, just-eat.co.uk"
```

There are other characteristics and peculiarities of `text item delimiters` that I've talked about in other answers on Stack Overflow, which you are free to search for.  But, for the vast majority of use cases, the information above is the most relevant.

---

#### AppleScript-ObjC

...because I saw your use of `stringValue()` and reference to a `.xib` window, I'll quickly give you the AppleScriptObjC equivalent for some of the above scenarios.

As I'm sure you'll know, all of the examples will only work if the script in which they appear has the following initial lines of code:

```
use framework "Foundation"
# use scripting additions -- if Standard Additions are needed

property this : a reference to the current application
property NSArray : a reference to NSArray of this
property NSString : a reference to NSString of this
```

I'll use the assignment-declaration for `enterDomains` in your code as a starting point, but instead of coercing it to `text`, I'll leave it in as the cocoa referenced object returned by `stringValue()` (the `--` comments out the coercion):

```
set enterDomains to myTextField's stringValue() -- as text
```

Therefore, `enterDomains` now contains an instance of an `NSString` class value object.  So:

1. Splitting a string:

   ```
   set theResults to enterDomains's componentsSeparatedByString:space
   ```
2. Joining a list of strings:

   ```
   theResults's componentsJoinedByString:", "
   ```
3. Replacing every space with a comma-space:

   ```
   my TextField's stringValue()'s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:space withString:", "
   return the result as text
   ```

See Apple's documentation on the [**`NSString`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring?language=objc) class for more stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```
set s to "alloresto.fr eat.ch eatnow.com.au just-eat.ca just-eat.co.uk"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
set theResults to every text item of s
-- {"alloresto.fr", "eat.ch", "eatnow.com.au", "just-eat.ca", "just-eat.co.uk"}
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
```

Go ye and do likewise.